# Error occurred in deployment step 'Activate Features': Invalid field name

Tags: visual-studio, content-type, feature-activation, field-definition

SharePoint Error message `Error occurred in deployment step 'Activate Features': Invalid field name.{guid}`

Answer (score 2):

Somewhere in your feature you have invalid GUID....check that and make it correct.
Use VS create GUID option.

Answer (score 0):

There is an attribute `Overwrite` for field and content-type definition. Add the attribute and make it true.
e.g.

```
<Field ID="guid"
       Name="---"
       StaticName="---"
       DisplayName="---"
       Type="---"
       Overwrite="True">
</Field>
```